# JavaScript HTML -> HTML transformer (templating engine)

Tags: open-source, library, javascript, html, templating

I need an open source JavaScript templating engine that takes a HTML file and a "template" and produces a new HTML file (for example, the original HTML with added header and sidebar and some JavaScript).

Comment: One solution is to use XSLT, but I'd like a simpler to learn and understand (for example, by non-programmers) solution.

Comment: The code should run in the user's browser.

Comment: What about EJS?

Comment: @Ace It seems EJS is not what I need: EJS uses some input data (JavaScript hash) for the template, but I need to get it from a HTML file not from a JavaScript hash.

Comment: I was thinking you'd take the html text and provide it as a value to the template. Is that not acceptable?

Comment: @Ace That would not work in practice, as the purpose is to analyse the HTML. It is hard to analyze HTML represented as text.

Comment: What if you could use xpath like with this library: [xpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath)

Comment: I feel like your need to analyse the HTML would make any solution more work than using XSLT.